# Find Gcd summation fast?

Tags: number-theory, summation, divisibility

Find the value of the summation:

$$
val=\left( \sum_{i=1}^a \sum_{j=1}^b\sum_{k=1}^c....\sum_{x=1}^p GCD(i,j,k,..x) \right)$$

Contraints

$2\leq$number of summation terms$\leq 500$, $1\leq a,b,c....p\leq 100000$

I applied brute force solution to solve it, but it takes too much time which is not acceptable

Comment: please show us what you have done..

Comment: i applied brute force it took lot of time

Comment: add that to the question..

Comment: A brute force that might take less time, and even lead to a closed form formula: Loop over all possible values of the gcd, try to figure out often that value appears in the sum. This approach can perhaps be refined a lot further.

Comment: Or you could try to add one variable at a time, using that $\gcd(i,j,\ldots,x,y)=\gcd(\gcd(i,j‚\ldots,x),y)$. Possibly combine that with my previous suggestion. There seem to be *lots* of things one can try.

Comment: i think there is closed formula
which i am not getting,can any one help me with that